# Where should I place the 'hide' bootstrap CSS class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>
        <span><?php echo get_the_title() ?></span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

When the resolution becomes 'extra small' as per bootstrap media calls I'd like the  tag to become hidden. So, question is, do I append 'hidden-xs' to the div class of 'title' or to the h1 tag itself using a 'class' attribute or to make a span class? The answer seems that they all work but I want to do it correctly - i.e. the 'correct' way. My hunch is that it should be within the div since that is the main parent? Thanks...

Comment: Well, there is no "correct way". You should go by the semantics. At which tag sounds logical to you? Go with that one. Also, you need to think about if you are going to display something else inside later.

Comment: It may also depend on the CSS for `.title` and/or `h1` and wether this has some visual effect even if the `span` is hidden.